# Why is there a performance difference when I pass a slice argument as value or a pointer?

Tags: performance, go, pointers, slice

I have the following code:

```
func AddToSliceByValue(mySlice []int) {
    for idx := range mySlice {
        mySlice[idx]++
    }
}

func AddToSliceByPointer(mySlice *[]int) {
    for idx := range *mySlice {
        (*mySlice)[idx]++
    }
}
```

My first thought was that the performance should be nearly the same because pass by value copies the slice header and pass by pointer would force me to dereferencing pointers but my benchmark shows something else:

```
func BenchmarkAddByValue(b *testing.B) {
    mySlice := rand.Perm(1000)
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        AddToSliceByValue(mySlice)
    }
}

func BenchmarkAddByPointer(b *testing.B) {
    mySlice := rand.Perm(1000)
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        AddToSliceByPointer(&mySlice)
    }
}
```

BenchmarkAddByValue-12       1151256          1035 ns/op

BenchmarkAddByPointer-12     2145110           525 ns/op

Can anyone explain to me why the difference in performance is so great?

I also added the assembly code for the two functions.

Assembly code for pass by value:

```
TEXT main.AddToSliceByValue(SB) /go_test/pointer/pointer_value.go
  pointer_value.go:4    0x1056f60       488b442410      MOVQ 0x10(SP), AX   
  pointer_value.go:4    0x1056f65       488b4c2408      MOVQ 0x8(SP), CX    
  pointer_value.go:4    0x1056f6a       31d2            XORL DX, DX     
  pointer_value.go:4    0x1056f6c       eb0e            JMP 0x1056f7c       
  pointer_value.go:5    0x1056f6e       488b1cd1        MOVQ 0(CX)(DX*8), BX    
  pointer_value.go:5    0x1056f72       48ffc3          INCQ BX         
  pointer_value.go:5    0x1056f75       48891cd1        MOVQ BX, 0(CX)(DX*8)    
  pointer_value.go:4    0x1056f79       48ffc2          INCQ DX         
  pointer_value.go:4    0x1056f7c       4839c2          CMPQ AX, DX     
  pointer_value.go:4    0x1056f7f       7ced            JL 0x1056f6e        
  pointer_value.go:4    0x1056f81       c3          RET         
  :-1           0x1056f82       cc          INT $0x3        
  :-1           0x1056f83       cc          INT $0x3        
  :-1           0x1056f84       cc          INT $0x3        
  :-1           0x1056f85       cc          INT $0x3        
  :-1           0x1056f86       cc          INT $0x3        
  :-1           0x1056f87       cc          INT $0x3        
  :-1           0x1056f88       cc          INT $0x3        
  :-1           0x1056f89       cc          INT $0x3        
  :-1           0x1056f8a       cc          INT $0x3        
  :-1           0x1056f8b       cc          INT $0x3        
  :-1           0x1056f8c       cc          INT $0x3        
  :-1           0x1056f8d       cc          INT $0x3        
  :-1           0x1056f8e       cc          INT $0x3        
  :-1           0x1056f8f       cc          INT $0x3        

TEXT main.main(SB) /go_test/pointer/pointer_value.go
  pointer_value.go:9    0x1056f90       65488b0c2530000000  MOVQ GS:0x30, CX            
  pointer_value.go:9    0x1056f99       483b6110        CMPQ 0x10(CX), SP           
  pointer_value.go:9    0x1056f9d       0f86a8000000        JBE 0x105704b               
  pointer_value.go:9    0x1056fa3       4883ec70        SUBQ $0x70, SP              
  pointer_value.go:9    0x1056fa7       48896c2468      MOVQ BP, 0x68(SP)           
  pointer_value.go:9    0x1056fac       488d6c2468      LEAQ 0x68(SP), BP           
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1056fb1       488d7c2418      LEAQ 0x18(SP), DI           
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1056fb6       0f57c0          XORPS X0, X0                
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1056fb9       488d7fd0        LEAQ -0x30(DI), DI          
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1056fbd       48896c24f0      MOVQ BP, -0x10(SP)          
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1056fc2       488d6c24f0      LEAQ -0x10(SP), BP          
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1056fc7       e849c6ffff      CALL 0x1053615              
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1056fcc       488b6d00        MOVQ 0(BP), BP              
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1056fd0       48c744242001000000  MOVQ $0x1, 0x20(SP)         
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1056fd9       48c744242802000000  MOVQ $0x2, 0x28(SP)         
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1056fe2       48c744243003000000  MOVQ $0x3, 0x30(SP)         
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1056feb       48c744243804000000  MOVQ $0x4, 0x38(SP)         
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1056ff4       48c744244005000000  MOVQ $0x5, 0x40(SP)         
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1056ffd       48c744244806000000  MOVQ $0x6, 0x48(SP)         
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1057006       48c744245007000000  MOVQ $0x7, 0x50(SP)         
  pointer_value.go:11   0x105700f       48c744245808000000  MOVQ $0x8, 0x58(SP)         
  pointer_value.go:11   0x1057018       48c744246009000000  MOVQ $0x9, 0x60(SP)         
  pointer_value.go:12   0x1057021       488d442418      LEAQ 0x18(SP), AX           
  pointer_value.go:12   0x1057026       48890424        MOVQ AX, 0(SP)              
  pointer_value.go:12   0x105702a       48c74424080a000000  MOVQ $0xa, 0x8(SP)          
  pointer_value.go:12   0x1057033       48c74424100a000000  MOVQ $0xa, 0x10(SP)         
  pointer_value.go:12   0x105703c       e81fffffff      CALL main.AddToSliceByValue(SB)     
  pointer_value.go:13   0x1057041       488b6c2468      MOVQ 0x68(SP), BP           
  pointer_value.go:13   0x1057046       4883c470        ADDQ $0x70, SP              
  pointer_value.go:13   0x105704a       c3          RET                 
  pointer_value.go:9    0x105704b       e8909cffff      CALL runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)   
  pointer_value.go:9    0x1057050       e93bffffff      JMP main.main(SB)
```

assembly code for pass by pointer:

```
TEXT main.AddToSliceByPointer(SB) /go_test/pointer/pointer_ref.go
  pointer_ref.go:3  0x1056f60       4883ec18        SUBQ $0x18, SP          
  pointer_ref.go:3  0x1056f64       48896c2410      MOVQ BP, 0x10(SP)       
  pointer_ref.go:3  0x1056f69       488d6c2410      LEAQ 0x10(SP), BP       
  pointer_ref.go:4  0x1056f6e       488b542420      MOVQ 0x20(SP), DX       
  pointer_ref.go:4  0x1056f73       488b5a08        MOVQ 0x8(DX), BX        
  pointer_ref.go:4  0x1056f77       31c0            XORL AX, AX         
  pointer_ref.go:4  0x1056f79       eb0e            JMP 0x1056f89           
  pointer_ref.go:5  0x1056f7b       488b3cc6        MOVQ 0(SI)(AX*8), DI        
  pointer_ref.go:5  0x1056f7f       48ffc7          INCQ DI             
  pointer_ref.go:5  0x1056f82       48893cc6        MOVQ DI, 0(SI)(AX*8)        
  pointer_ref.go:4  0x1056f86       48ffc0          INCQ AX             
  pointer_ref.go:4  0x1056f89       4839d8          CMPQ BX, AX         
  pointer_ref.go:4  0x1056f8c       7d0e            JGE 0x1056f9c           
  pointer_ref.go:5  0x1056f8e       488b4a08        MOVQ 0x8(DX), CX        
  pointer_ref.go:5  0x1056f92       488b32          MOVQ 0(DX), SI          
  pointer_ref.go:5  0x1056f95       4839c8          CMPQ CX, AX         
  pointer_ref.go:5  0x1056f98       72e1            JB 0x1056f7b            
  pointer_ref.go:5  0x1056f9a       eb0a            JMP 0x1056fa6           
  pointer_ref.go:4  0x1056f9c       488b6c2410      MOVQ 0x10(SP), BP       
  pointer_ref.go:4  0x1056fa1       4883c418        ADDQ $0x18, SP          
  pointer_ref.go:4  0x1056fa5       c3          RET             
  pointer_ref.go:5  0x1056fa6       e8b5c4ffff      CALL runtime.panicIndex(SB) 
  pointer_ref.go:5  0x1056fab       90          NOPL                
  :-1           0x1056fac       cc          INT $0x3            
  :-1           0x1056fad       cc          INT $0x3            
  :-1           0x1056fae       cc          INT $0x3            
  :-1           0x1056faf       cc          INT $0x3            

TEXT main.main(SB) /go_test/pointer/pointer_ref.go
  pointer_ref.go:9  0x1056fb0       65488b0c2530000000  MOVQ GS:0x30, CX            
  pointer_ref.go:9  0x1056fb9       483b6110        CMPQ 0x10(CX), SP           
  pointer_ref.go:9  0x1056fbd       0f86b2000000        JBE 0x1057075               
  pointer_ref.go:9  0x1056fc3       4883ec78        SUBQ $0x78, SP              
  pointer_ref.go:9  0x1056fc7       48896c2470      MOVQ BP, 0x70(SP)           
  pointer_ref.go:9  0x1056fcc       488d6c2470      LEAQ 0x70(SP), BP           
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1056fd1       488d7c2408      LEAQ 0x8(SP), DI            
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1056fd6       0f57c0          XORPS X0, X0                
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1056fd9       488d7fd0        LEAQ -0x30(DI), DI          
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1056fdd       48896c24f0      MOVQ BP, -0x10(SP)          
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1056fe2       488d6c24f0      LEAQ -0x10(SP), BP          
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1056fe7       e829c6ffff      CALL 0x1053615              
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1056fec       488b6d00        MOVQ 0(BP), BP              
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1056ff0       48c744241001000000  MOVQ $0x1, 0x10(SP)         
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1056ff9       48c744241802000000  MOVQ $0x2, 0x18(SP)         
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1057002       48c744242003000000  MOVQ $0x3, 0x20(SP)         
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x105700b       48c744242804000000  MOVQ $0x4, 0x28(SP)         
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1057014       48c744243005000000  MOVQ $0x5, 0x30(SP)         
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x105701d       48c744243806000000  MOVQ $0x6, 0x38(SP)         
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1057026       48c744244007000000  MOVQ $0x7, 0x40(SP)         
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x105702f       48c744244808000000  MOVQ $0x8, 0x48(SP)         
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1057038       48c744245009000000  MOVQ $0x9, 0x50(SP)         
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1057041       488d442408      LEAQ 0x8(SP), AX            
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1057046       4889442458      MOVQ AX, 0x58(SP)           
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x105704b       48c74424600a000000  MOVQ $0xa, 0x60(SP)         
  pointer_ref.go:11 0x1057054       48c74424680a000000  MOVQ $0xa, 0x68(SP)         
  pointer_ref.go:12 0x105705d       488d442458      LEAQ 0x58(SP), AX           
  pointer_ref.go:12 0x1057062       48890424        MOVQ AX, 0(SP)              
  pointer_ref.go:12 0x1057066       e8f5feffff      CALL main.AddToSliceByPointer(SB)   
  pointer_ref.go:13 0x105706b       488b6c2470      MOVQ 0x70(SP), BP           
  pointer_ref.go:13 0x1057070       4883c478        ADDQ $0x78, SP              
  pointer_ref.go:13 0x1057074       c3          RET                 
  pointer_ref.go:9  0x1057075       e8669cffff      CALL runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)   
  pointer_ref.go:9  0x105707a       e931ffffff      JMP main.main(SB)
```

Comment: Likely different compiler optimization. Check the generated assembly code.

Comment: Microbenchmark is a different word for lie. Also note that you microbenchmark includes the time for rand.Perm. If you are interested on the details why and how the compiler produces different code: Ask on golang-nuts.

Comment: Hey Volker, I thought if I place things outside of the benchmark loop, it will not affect the timing.

Comment: in your case this is of litlle interest to reset the timer as anyway rand.Perm will roughly impact your results in a constant manner and that because we are looking at the difference of the two versions, not their exact timings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that my variance was too high:

```
AddByValue-12    5.41µs ±15%
AddByPointer-12  5.30µs ± 4%
```

with `go test -benchmem -count 5  -benchtime=1000000x -bench=. ./...` I was able to reduce the variance in the test results and could confirm my first assumption that the results should be approximately equal:

```
AddByValue-12    5.04µs ± 1%
AddByPointer-12  5.17µs ± 1%
```

According to the comments the main reason for the high variance was that I did not reset the timer after the benchmark setup.

With the following code and a lower benchtime I also reduced the variance:

```
func BenchmarkAddByValue(b *testing.B) {
    mySlice := rand.Perm(10000)
    b.ResetTimer()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        AddToSliceByValue(mySlice)
    }
}

func BenchmarkAddByPointer(b *testing.B) {
    mySlice := rand.Perm(10000)
    b.ResetTimer()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        AddToSliceByPointer(&mySlice)
    }
}
```

Results:

```
AddByValue-12    5.03µs ± 0%
AddByPointer-12  5.17µs ± 1%
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I could not reproduce your benchmark...

```golang
package main_test

import (
    "math/rand"
    "testing"
)

func AddToSliceByValue(mySlice []int) {
    for idx := range mySlice {
        mySlice[idx]++
    }
}

func AddToSliceByPointer(mySlice *[]int) {
    for idx := range *mySlice {
        (*mySlice)[idx]++
    }
}

func BenchmarkAddByValue(b *testing.B) {
    mySlice := rand.Perm(1000)
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        AddToSliceByValue(mySlice)
    }
}

func BenchmarkAddByPointer(b *testing.B) {
    mySlice := rand.Perm(1000)
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        AddToSliceByPointer(&mySlice)
    }
}
```

```sh
$ go test -bench=. -benchmem -count=4
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: test/bencslice
BenchmarkAddByValue-4        3010280           385 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAddByValue-4        3118990           385 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAddByValue-4        3117450           384 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAddByValue-4        3109251           386 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAddByPointer-4      2012487           610 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAddByPointer-4      2009690           594 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAddByPointer-4      2009222           594 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAddByPointer-4      1850820           596 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      test/bencslice  13.476s
$ go version
go version go1.15.2 linux/amd64
```

Anyways, the behavior might be dependent of many factors, first of all the version of the runtime. Understanding the intrinsec is of little interest as long as you can test, reproduce and monitor.

Answer (score 0):

This is general issue with "lower level" languages. When you pass by value that means you are actually copying the data. Here is how that works.

When you pass by reference :

- The copy of the reference is created and passed to method ( reference is most likely 8 bytes, so this is fast )
- You read out the data behind the reference ( this is also fast, since the reference is most likely in the CPU cache )

In case of pass by value:

- The block of memory is allocated to store the data you passed in ( slow )
- The data is copied into the newly allocated block of memory ( maybe fast, maybe slow )
- Then your data is accessed via references ( maybe slow, maybe fast, depending if data landed in cache or not )

Comment: A function receiving a slice gets a copy of the slice header (len, cap, pointer to data) which should also be fast.

Comment: The only thing that's passed by value here is the slice, not the values that the slice refers to. [Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/K_sXsT8lSUK).